Detect Modern Standby/S0 from a Windows Service
I have a Windows Service which performs network activity. This service is distributed across a few hundred PCs with a wide variety of hardware, including some tablets with either WiFi or cellular connections.
The problem I'm facing is that when the PC goes into MODERN STANDBY/S0 state, the service continues to run but encounters network errors. Login within the application terminates the service if these failures continue for a long period, and (normally) the service recovery options will then restart the service. Our experience has shown that this can resolve a number of network related issues without user intervention that cannot be resolved normally in-process. However while in S0, the service restart fails as the initial network connection cannot be made.
So the way I need the service to behave in Modern Standby/S0 differs to how it has to behave normally (e.g. disable the watchdog so it doesn't terminate, don't attempt network operations, etc).
I have now spent several fruitless days trying to find a way of detecting when the system enters or is in Modern Standby/S0. I've so far tried the Windows Service power notifications, which work for all EXCEPT Modern Standby. I have tried querying the PowerState in the WMI Win32_ComputerSystem class, but this seems to just return Unknown all the time on the two systems I've tried it on (other properties are populated as I'd expect). Googling for a solution has been an exercise in frustration, and most articles relate only to disabling S0 (not an option), are out of date and don't deal with S0, or have otherwise been unhelpful.
Any pointers welcome. A working example in C#/.NET would be ideal, but just a pointer to an Windows API that gives me the right information would be enough.
Thank you.

The following may be of interest: What is Modern Standby

Key point is "Network adapters that do not support modern connected standby are turned off (D3)." so you may want to update your network adapter drivers. Also your service should really be reslient in the face of network failures, these are pretty normal and should not cause service shutdown.

The service is VERY resilient RE network outages. The intrenal watchdog is just for those cases we can't solve in process (e.g. client's dynamic proxy changing, certain DNS server changes - cases where throwing away the existing connection in code and receating it simply doesn't solve the problem),

Our system is desiged for intermittent/occational connectivity, and the tablets affected are running at remote sites. Anything that will stretch their battery life (like powering down WiFi) is a good thing. I just need to know WHEN it occurs so I can disable the watchdog.

I've figured it out using an EventLogWatcher and watch it for EventId 507 (Modern StandBy exit) and 506 (Modern StandBy Entry).
It works for me but the issue is that it seems really unreliable. There are more entries than what I expected during a manual sleep and wakeup. I believe doing recovery based on these entries might cause other new issues.

You can detect support for modern standby by checking the AoAc field returned by GetPwrCapabilities()
Normal applications can register for notification of modern standby/resume using RegisterSuspendResumeNotification(). Things are more tricky for services running in session 0. These are not sent notifications. We overcame this problem by launching a helper process that ran in another session and notified the service when suspend/resume were notified.
